# Pyspark : find the center in a daterange and split the dataframe in two

Tags: date, datetime, pyspark, split

My problem seems pretty easy but I'm not able to find a solution in spark!

Let's assume I have a similar data frame

```
+---------------+---------------+
|entry_time     | a             |
+---------------+---------------+
|     2021-12-31|     7         |
+---------------+---------------+
|     2021-11-28|   6           |
+---------------+---------------+
|     2021-10-04|  5            |
+---------------+---------------+
|     2021-09-01|  7            |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to split this dataframe into two, based on the entry time.
The first df will have the data from the entry_time min to the 'center', while the second one the remaining data from the center of entry_time to the maximum value.

In this case, the minimum is the 1st of September and the maximum the 31st of December, a period of 120 days. So the first df will have the data from the 1st of September to the 31st of October, while the second one from the 1st of November to 31st December.

I would like a function which basically split into two my df according to the middle data in entry time.

Any ideas to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,  I did it

```
def create_dfs(df):

    date_max = df.agg({'entry_time': 'max'}).head()[0]
    date_min = df.agg({'entry_time': 'min'}).head()[0]

    dd = date_min + (date_max - date_min) / 2

    df_pre  = df.where((df.entry_time < dd))
    df_post = df.where((df.entry_time >= dd))

    return df_pre, df_post

df_pre, df_post = create_dfs(df)
```